# Get preferred language of a user in a Django managment command

Tags: django, django-i18n

I am using Djangos management commands to send user notification emails, which I would like to send them in their preferred language. I guess I will have to store the preferred language in their profile. Or is there any other way how I could avoid that?

I don't want to add a "select your language" option in the user profile, but instead use the latest language the user was browsing the website with. What would be the way to update his language setting?

Comment: One approach would be to write a piece of middleware that, on every request, stores the requested language to the profile of the logged-in user.